# Verificando se valor existe em um array através de campo de busca

Tags: javascript, array, algoritmo-de-busca

Em javascript puro posso usar `indexOf()`, algo assim:

```
var chaves = ['wmv','3gp','mp4','mp3','avi'];
if(chaves.indexOf("avi") != -1)
{  
    alert("Ok!");
}
```

Mas se tratando de um *campo de busca* estou tentando deste modo:

```
<html>
   <body>
       <input type="text" id="txt" onblur="verifica()"/>
   </body>
   <script>
       var chaves = ['wmv','3gp','mp4','mp3','avi'];
       var item = document.getElementById('txt').value;
       function verifica()  {
            for(var i = 0; i < chaves.length; i++) 
            {
               if(chaves[i].length == item)     {
                   alert("SIM")
               } else {
                   alert("NAO")
               }
            }
       }
   </script>
</html>
```

O pior é que já fiz uma vez e agora não me lembro mais.. se alguém puder ajudar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se pode usar igual seu primeiro exemplo, só deve alterar sua função `verifica()`:

```js
function verifica() {
  var chaves = ['wmv', '3gp', 'mp4', 'mp3', 'avi'];
  var item = document.getElementById('txt').value;
  if (chaves.indexOf(item) > -1) {
    alert("Encontrou");
  } else {
    alert("Não encontrou");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" onblur="verifica()" />
```

***Referencia:*** [JavaScript String indexOf() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

onde o retorna for `> -1` foi encontrado o índice que está a pesquisa se for `-1` não foi encontrado.

Answer (score 6):

Hoje existe uma alternativa mais atual e funcional para descobrir se determinado valor pertence a uma array. Pode-se utilizar o método `Array.prototype.includes()` do `ES7`.

Reescrevendo a resposta, teríamos o seguinte código:

```
const verifica = (item) => {
   const chaves = ['wmv', '3gp', 'mp4', 'mp3', 'avi'];
   chaves.includes(item) ? alert("Encontrou") : alert("Não encontrou");
}
```

Utilizando da seguinte maneira:

```
verifica(document.getElementById('txt').value);
```

**Porém** o método, `includes()` não é suportado em navegadores mais antigos, isso pode ser um problema se você não utiliza de algum transpilador para fazer a conversão de ES7 para ES5.

Segue abaixo a lista dos navegadores suportados:

Compatibilidade ([can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=indexof)) `Array.prototype.indexOf`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Compatibilidade ([can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=includes)) `Array.prototype.includes`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Referência:** https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp

Comment: Valeu por compartilhar!