# Quero procurar por nome de qualquer função a partir de um campo de busca

Tags: javascript, string, query, funções, algoritmo-de-busca

Gente... como eu posso fazer um sistema em que o `input text` recebe um nome duma `function`.. então ele busca seu nome internamente com o nome que está na `string`.
tipo...

No Html faço o seguinte:

```
<input type="text" id="seuInput" onkeyup="keyupFunction()">
```

No javascript:

```
function keyupFunction() {
   // codigo para achar o nome em certa função
   var valor_do_campo_aqui = document.getElementById("seuinput").value;
}
```

Por exemplo:

Tenho a `function carro() { ... }`

este "carro" é o nome duma certa função. E preciso abri-lo para chamar certos dados nele.

---

A pergunta remete a algo quase, repito quase como esta - [Verificando se valor existe em um array através de campo de busca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173589/verificando-se-valor-existe-em-um-array-atrav%C3%A9s-de-campo-de-busca)

Para exemplo, espero receber apenas um `alert` - *se ela existe ou não*.

Como posso usar uma busca pra achar isso e demais funções que possa criar posteriormente!?

Comment: é algo assim? > https://codepen.io/alexlupoz/pen/ELpevJ

Comment: Vou elaborar um com inner HTML e posto como resposta, pra posterioridade que também acabar achando teu post por ventura e quiser sanar tais dúvidas. Um momento.

Comment: Embora as respostas que tem sejam boas e respondam ao que perguntou, dificilmente serão o que você quer fazer. Se mostrar a forma e o local onde as vai utilizar, será mais facil de aconselhar uma alternativa.

Comment: Mas em que essas pesquisas diferem ? Não serão todas as pesquisas generalizáveis para utilizarem uma só função ? Isso é algo que com o pouco contexto dado na pergunta não me é possivel de responder

Comment: @Isac Bom, se eu fosse postar muito código ou dizer em mínimos detalhes, certamente receberia um DowVote até porque não seria o foco do contexto e a ética do site. Aqui no pt.stackoverflow.com tem como meta elaborar pergunta de maneira isolada para cada qual seja o problema, que no meu caso era esse da questão. Não poderia eu dizer em muitas linhas e/ou postar códigos avantajados demais para a pergunta. Talvez alguém ou algum usuário ficaria confuso e viria a fazer perguntas nos cometários pedindo maiores informações. Por isso só postei e perguntei de modo isolado o que não sabia fazer.

Comment: Sim eu percebo e concordo que fazer isso nesta questão iria desvirtuá-la. Estou apenas a tentar alertar-lhe que muito provavelmente está num [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%C3%A9-o-problema-xy)  e por isso deve repensar um pouco a forma como está a tentar resolver o problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma de saber se qualquer função existe e chamá-la é usando `typeof()`:

**Exemplo:**

```js
function carro(){
   alert("A função carro existe");
}

function keyupFunction(f) {
   if(typeof(window[f]) == "function"){
      window[f]();
   }
}
```

```html
Digite, por exemplo, 'carro':
<br>
<input type="text" id="seuInput" onkeyup="keyupFunction(this.value)">
```

> **Obs.:** neste exemplo, só irá encontrar funções com escopo global.

Comment: @Diego Henrique, a solução do DVD é a solução semântica que precisa. O quê dei foi apenas um exemplo de sintax bem simples. Creio que ele mereça a escolha de resposta certa, pois se adequará melhor ao seu projeto. Há como mudar, não?

Comment: @AlexLupóz Seu pedido é uma ordem patrão, apenas sigo instinto sobre os meus dados votos quem primeiramente responder de prontidão leva. Mas estornarei o Voto conforme me pediste

Comment: Obrigado. soluções semânticas são sempre a melhor solução.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, se não for usar para algum sistema que demande diversos nomes salvos (não seria nada semântico criar 30 subfunções hehehe), aqui está:

```js
//funções filhas
function funcCarro(minhaVar){
  document.getElementById('funcFilhas').innerHTML = 'O termo <strong> ' + minhaVar + '</strong> existe em nosso sistema!';
}

function funcPessoa(minhaVar){
  document.getElementById('funcFilhas').innerHTML = 'O termo <strong> ' + minhaVar + '</strong> existe em nosso sistema!';
}

//função pai
//Esta função chamará a respectiva função filha digitada no input
function funcao(minhaVar) {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = '<hr><h3 style="color: blue;">Você digitou: <span style="color: red;">' + minhaVar + '</span></h3>';
  
  if(minhaVar == 'carro')
  {
    funcCarro(minhaVar);
  }
  else if(minhaVar == 'pessoa')
  {
    funcPessoa(minhaVar);
  }
  else
    {
  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = '<hr>O termo digitado não existe em nosso sistema!';
      
document.getElementById('funcFilhas').innerHTML = '';
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<label>Busca: <input type="text" onkeyup="funcao(this.value)"></label>
<pre style="color: silver; font-size: 12px; margin: 5px 0 0 0;">Dica: Digite "carro" ou "pessoa"</pre>
<div id="output"></div>
<div id="funcFilhas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Bons estudos!