# Como localizar um vetor usando uma função em JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

QuerO retornar `true` or `false` caso localizasse o ReactJS no vetor, porém sempre retorna `false`, não queria ter a resposta de cara, mas  uma explicação do por que esta dando errado grato desde ja.

```
var skills = [ "JavaScript", "ReactJS", "React Native"];

          function temhabilidade(skills){

        var resultado = skills.indexOf('ReactJS'); 
        if(resultado == 'ReactJS'){
          return true;
        }else{
          return false;
        }          
      }     
      var mostra = temhabilidade('ReactJS');
      console.log(mostra);
```

Comment: O retorno do indexOf é o índice onde a string foi encontrada (ou -1 caso não tenha sido encontrada).

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Verificando se valor existe em um array através de campo de busca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173589/verificando-se-valor-existe-em-um-array-atrav%c3%a9s-de-campo-de-busca)

Answer (score 5):

O método [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) retorna o primeiro índice em que o elemento pode ser encontrado no array e retorna -1 caso o elemento não seja encontrado.

Nesse seu caso seria melhor usar o método [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contains)

```
function temhabilidade(skills){
    if (skills.includes('ReactJS'))
        return true;

    return false;   
}
```

Comment: Em vez do `if`, pode ser simplesmente: `return skills.includes('ReactJS')`

Answer (score 2):

Está dando false porque o indexOf não retorna um booleano, e também não vai retornar o valor 'ReactJS', então, **resultado nunca vai ser igual a 'ReactJS'**.

> O método indexOf() retorna o primeiro índice em que o elemento pode ser encontrado no array, retorna -1 caso o mesmo não esteja presente.

O legal seria nessa função você criar um filtro com o próprio **filter**

```js
const skils = ['NodeJS', 'ReactJS', 'PHP']
skils.filter(function(skill){
  if(skill === 'ReactJS') {
    return console.log(true)
  }
})
```

Óbvio, desse jeito que dei de exemplo acho que não se encaixa em nenhuma aplicação, mas é somente pra exemplificar.

- [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro)
- [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro)

Answer (score 2):

Um método muito bom de se utilizar também é o [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), com ele através de uma função de callback é retornado o valor booleano **`true`** se pelo menos um dos elementos no array casar com a condição.

```js
const skils = ['NodeJS', 'ReactJS', 'PHP']

function temhabilidade(skills) {
  return skils.some(skill => skill == skills)
}

let mostra = temhabilidade('ReactJS');
console.log(mostra);
```

> O pq do seu código estar retornando sempre false, já foi explicado pelos colegas.

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso você está renomeando a variável da array

```js
var skills = [ "JavaScript", "ReactJS", "React Native"];

function temhabilidade(search){
  var resultado = skills.indexOf(search); 
  return resultado > 0 ? true : false;
}     

var mostra = temhabilidade('ReactJS');
console.log('achou ReactJS? '+ mostra);

var mostra = temhabilidade('ABC');
console.log('achou ABC? '+ mostra);
```