# Condicional na API em Java Script

Tags: javascript, node.js

sou novato em NodeJs com JavaScript, peguei um exemplo pronto e quero apenas adicionar uma condição no corpo da API do tipo: Caso aquele valor exista mostra a mensagem na chamada da API via Insonmia ou Postman e não deixa incluir.

```
Código no VSCode

const express = require('express')
const server = express()

server.use(express.json())


const users = ["aa", "bb", "cc", "ddd"]

server.get('/users', (req, res) => {

return res.json(users)
})

server.post('/users', (req, res) => {
    const { name } = req.body
    users.push(name)
       if (name == "aaaa") {
        console.log("Registro existente.")

      return res.json(users)
  
})

server.listen(3000)

Chamada API
{
"name": "aa"
}

via
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Verificando se valor existe em um array através de campo de busca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173589/verificando-se-valor-existe-em-um-array-atrav%c3%a9s-de-campo-de-busca)

Comment: Esse código não compila.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você poderia fazer a verificação antes de incluir o elemento no array.

Ao detectar que o elemento já existe, basta fazer o envio da mensagem de erro.

```
server.post('/users', (req, res) => {
    const { name } = req.body
    if (name && users.includes(name)) {
        res.json({"msg": "Registro existente"})
        return 
    } else if (name) {
        users.push(name)
    }
    res.json(users)      
})
```

O `else if` é necessário para prevenir a inserção do valor `null` no array `users`, caso não seja enviado a chave `name` no `request.body`

Documentação do [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: Muito agradecido... Deu super certo..